# OpenLayers drawing circle doesn't work for version 5.3.0

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I had to downgrade my OpenLayers version a bit from 6.1.1 to 5.3.0.
After this, I've noticed, that I can't draw the circle anymore.

From the following code:

```
     var circleInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry, projection) {
      if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([]);
      }
      var center = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[0], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
      var last = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[1], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
      var radius = ol.sphere.getDistance(center, last);
      var circle = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(center, radius);
      circle.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
      geometry.setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
      return geometry;
    },
    type: 'Circle',
    source: vectorLayer.getSource(),
    stopClick: true
  });
  circleInteraction.setActive(false);
  circleInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
  circleInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
    var title = prompt("Please provide the name", "default");
    var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefinied");
    var id = x++
    e.feature.setProperties({
      'Id': id,
      'Name': title,
      'Value': value,
     });
  });
```

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getCode')
> at
> var center = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[0], projection, 'EPSG:4326');

Is it something, which I could replace this line of code?

The full code is available here:

https://mktest.opx.pl/

Comment: The projection was not passed to the geometry function until version 6.  You should use the view projection `map.getView().getProjection()`

Answer (score 0):

We can create the circle by changing the parameters of the star shape

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69301542/openlayers-cant-draw-the-star

```
 var circleInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry, projection) {
   if (!geometry) {
    geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([]);
  }

   var center = coordinates[0];
      var last = coordinates[1];
      var dx = center[0] - last[0];
      var dy = center[1] - last[1];
      var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      //var radius = 10;
      var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      var newCoordinates = [];
      var numPoints = 48;
      for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
        var angle = rotation + i * 2 * Math.PI / numPoints;
        var fraction = i % 1 === 0 ? 1 : 1;
        var offsetX = radius * fraction * Math.cos(angle);
        var offsetY = radius * fraction * Math.sin(angle);
        newCoordinates.push([center[0] + offsetX, center[1] + offsetY]);
      }
      newCoordinates.push(newCoordinates[0].slice());
      geometry.setCoordinates([newCoordinates]);
      return geometry;
    },
     type: 'Circle',
    source: vectorLayer.getSource(),
    stopClick: true
   });
   circleInteraction.setActive(false);
   circleInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
```

where `var numPoints = 48` instead of 12 and `var fraction - i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : 1;` instead of 1: 0.5